# Swift iOS EXC_BREAKPOINT crash in production

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crash

Firebase is reporting that a large number of production users are getting the following fatal crash:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000101076f0c

0  SCLAlertView                   0xaf0c SCLAlertView.showTitle(_:subTitle:timeout:completeText:style:colorStyle:colorTextButton:circleIconImage:animationStyle:) + 5128 (<compiler-generated>:5128)
1  SCLAlertView                   0x9a7c SCLAlertView.showSuccess(_:subTitle:closeButtonTitle:timeout:colorStyle:colorTextButton:circleIconImage:animationStyle:) + 108
2  SCLAlertView                   0x98d0 SCLAlertView.showNotice(_:subTitle:closeButtonTitle:timeout:colorStyle:colorTextButton:circleIconImage:animationStyle:) + 48
3  app-production                 0xf9414 promptForOptionalUpdate(_:) + 139 (AppTheme.swift:139)
4  app-production                 0xfa838 partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in isUpdateAvailable(completion:) + 59 (UpdatesCheck.swift:59)
5  app-production                 0x1c2d4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4363469524 (<compiler-generated>:4363469524)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x2320 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x3eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x126a4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x122f4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
10 CoreFoundation                 0x98c28 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
11 CoreFoundation                 0x7a560 __CFRunLoopRun + 1992
12 CoreFoundation                 0x7f3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
13 GraphicsServices               0x135c GSEventRunModal + 164
14 UIKitCore                      0x39cf58 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
15 UIKitCore                      0x39cbbc UIApplicationMain + 340
16 app-production                 0x5a94 main + 12 (AppDelegate.swift:12)
17 ???                            0x1b9450dec (Missing)
```

I am perplexed as to how `EXC_BREAKPOINT` can trigger in production code that clearly has no breakpoints in it.

The problem must be restricted to certain devices as I am unable to reproduce the problem locally in either the simulator or a real device including a production device.  I have scrutinised the `SCLAlertView.showTitle` function and can find no issues.

Any advice on how I can track down the cause of this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess is a threading issue at apptheme.swift:139